# Is it possible to overload new operator for allocating something like 2d array in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

Is it possible to overload global new and global delete operators in C++ for allocation and deallocation of 2d block of memory with given "height" and "width"?

Comment: memory isnt 2d, but you can allocate a block of size `width*height`

Comment: Sorry, I formulated idea incorrectly. Can I somehow allocate block of size width*height and use it with subscript operators as 2d array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/1216776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to overload new operator for allocating something like 2d array in C++?

Yes.

> but can I get some code example?

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[][10]> arr {new int[n][10]};
```

> with given "height" and "width"?

Only if the inner dimensions are compile time constant. Only the outer dimension may be dynamic.

It is easy to translate between a dynamic single dimensional flat array, and a multi dimensional one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I get some code example?

Comment: @Someone I wrote an example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the global new operator takes one parameter, so you can not provide it with both "height" and "width". And, the global new/delete operator will be used by not only the code you wrote, but also the library you use, for example std::string, std::vector. So, make such a change may cause nasty problems.